# K-means Cluster Centers Are the Same Every Run Although It Is Randomly Initialized

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means, flann

I have an application where I need to implement K-means myself. I was trying my implementation in a small program to see how things are going; however, I find it really confusing that I get the exact same cluster centers every time I run the program. I am surprised because my cluster centers are randomly initialized, and I am using FLANN to update the clusters (both should make the output nondeterministic, right?). I'm probably missing something, and would appreciate some help.

```
cv::Mat kMeans(cv::Mat data, int k, int max_itr){
    cv::Mat centroids = cv::Mat(cv::Size(data.cols, k), data.type());
    std::vector<int> cluster_ids(data.rows, 0);

    //randomly initialize centroids
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int idx = rand() % data.rows;
        data.row(idx).copyTo(centroids.row(i));
    }

    int itr = 0;
    cv::flann::Index kdtree(centroids, cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4));
    cv::Mat indices, dists;
    
    //TODO: add tolerance stopping condition
    while (itr < max_itr)
    {
        //assign data points to centroids
        for(int i = 0; i < data.rows; i++)
        {
            kdtree.knnSearch(data.row(i), indices, dists, 1, cv::flann::SearchParams(32));
            cluster_ids[i] = indices.data[0];
        } 
        //update centroids
        for(int i = 0; i < centroids.rows; i++)
        {
            cv::Mat sum = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(data.cols, 1), data.type()); 
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < data.rows; j++)
            {
                if(cluster_ids[j] != i) {continue;}
                sum += data.row(j);
                count++;
            }
            centroids.row(i) = sum / float(count);
        }
       itr += 1;
    }
return centroids;
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat_<float> data;
    cv::Mat_<float> centroids;
    cv::Mat dst;
    //initialize with dummy data
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    { 
        cv::Mat row = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 3) << float(i), float(i), float(i));
        data.push_back(row);
    }
    centroids = kMeans(data, 20, 20);
    std::cout << centroids << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this line:

```
std::srand(std::time(nullptr)); // use current time as seed for random generator
```

at the start of your program to get different sequences from the `rand` function every time you run the program.

You can use some other seed if you want, but you still need to call `srand` with some source of randomness at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV also provides a Random Number Generator class: [cv::RNG](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dd6/classcv_1_1RNG.html). You can use it like this:

```
//Create the RNG object:
cv::RNG& rng = cv::theRNG();
//Seed it:
rng.state = cv::getTickCount();

//Print it:
std::cout<<"Random Number: "<<(int)rng<<std::endl;
```